# Formatting a string in D

Tags: string-formatting, d

I read on D's documentation that it's possible to format strings with arguments as print statements, such as the following:

```
float x = 100 / 3.0;
writefln("Number: %.*g", 2, x);

Number: 33.33
```

However, I'm wondering how I would do this if I just wanted the string equivalent, without printing it. I've looked at the std.format library but that seems way to messy for something I only need to use once. Is there anything a little bit more clear available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `std.string` or `std.format` and use the `format` function.

```
import std.string;

void main()
{
    float x = 100 / 3.0;
    auto s = format("Number: %.*g", 4, x);
    assert(s == "Number: 33.33");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I must've missed that function when I was reading the documentation.